# bash output to csv columns

Tags: bash, csv

**BIG EDIT for a better understanding:** is there a possibility in **bash** to put my output (lines) to columns in csv files (regarding the following challenge).

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## get ports, status, vlan

devices=`ls *.txt`

for device in $devices
do
        output=`echo $device | awk -F"." {'print $1'}`
        echo "Port;Status;VLAN\r" > $output".csv"

        port=`cat $device | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=";"}; /Fa[0-9]|Gi[0-9]|Te[0-9]/ && /disabled|connected/ {print $1}'`
        stat=`cat $device | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=";"}; /Fa[0-9]|Gi[0-9]|Te[0-9]/ && /disabled|connected/ {print $0}' | awk 'match($0,"connected|disabled.*"){print substr($0,RSTART)}' | awk '{print $1}'`
        vlan=`cat $device | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=";"}; /Fa[0-9]|Gi[0-9]|Te[0-9]/ && /disabled|connected/ {print $0}' | awk 'match($0,"connected|disabled.*"){print substr($0,RSTART)}' | awk '{print $2}'`


        var=$(paste -d, <(echo "$port") <(echo "$stat") <(echo "$vlan"))
        echo "$var" >> output."csv"
done
```

.

```
<input-file.txt>
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type
Fa0/1                        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/2                        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/3                        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/4                        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/5                        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/6                        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/7                        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/8                        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/9                        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/10    xxxx-xxx-xxx 0004. connected    3            full    100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/11    xxxx-xxx-xxx bge0  connected    3          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/12    xxxx-xxx-xxx iLO   connected    2          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/13    xxxx-xxx-xxx bge0  connected    2          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/14                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/15    xxxx-xxx-vpn bge0  connected    4          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/16    xxxx-xxx-vpn ilO   connected    2          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/17    xxxx-xxx xx.xx.xx. connected    2          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/18    xxxxxx-xxx1        connected    2          a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/19                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/20                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/21    xxxxx-xxxxx        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/22    xxxxxx-xxx         disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/23    xxxx-xxx           disabled     2            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/24    xxxxxx-xxxx        disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/25                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/26                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/27                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/28                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/29                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/30                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/31                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/32                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/33                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/34                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/35                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/36                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/37                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/38                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/39                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/40                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/41                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/42                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/43                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/44                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/45                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/46                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/47                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Fa0/48                       disabled     1            auto   auto 10/100BaseTX
Gi0/1     Xxxxxxxx Xxxxx xx  connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX SFP
Gi0/2     Xxxxx xxxxxxx Xxx  connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 1000BaseSX SFP
Gi0/3                        disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
Gi0/4                        disabled     1            auto   auto Not Present
```

result of script output should be:

```
<output.csv>
| Port   | Status    | VLAN |
| Fa0/1  | disabled  |  1   |
| Fa0/2  | disabled  |  1   |
| Fa0/3  | disabled  |  1   |
| Fa0/4  | disabled  |  1   |
| Fa0/5  | disabled  |  1   |
| Fa0/6  | disabled  |  1   |
| Fa0/7  | disabled  |  1   |
| Fa0/8  | disabled  |  1   |
| Fa0/9  | disabled  |  1   |
| Fa0/10 | connected |  3   |
and so on
```

Issue: after trying the "paste" command (thanks guys) .. i'm getting the following error: *Syntax error: "(" unexpected*

Comment: It would be useful if you included a short sample of one of the `.txt` files in the question.

Comment: It would be more useful to put a short sample of your input data in the question and show the corresponding desired output. You can also remove the output of your individual awk commands from the question.

Comment: thanks for ur hint, never used FIELDWIDTHS before, but the mentioned input file shows only 1/10 of the whole config file content. because the output of different queries seems to have the same structure. thus, there are more matches for "10 19 13 11", even after expanding the FW query - and yes, i'm using gnu awk 4

Comment: i did a workaround to fix my "syntax" issue... by writing the output of my queries to files and afterwards doing "paste f1 f2 f3" ... works perfectly. solved!

Comment: indeed, i did!! :) thank you very much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU awk, the lines inside your loop can be compressed to something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS = "10 18 13 11"}{printf "| %s | %s | %s |\n", $1,$3,$4}' "$device"
```

If you have a different awk, the command will be more complicated but it is still possible to do what you want in one awk statement.

Some points on your attempt:

- Make sure you put quotes around variables in your script (use `"$details"` instead of `$details`), as this protects you from a whole class of bugs caused by spaces in file names.
- You don't need to use `cat` to pass the content of a file to `awk`. It's rare that you need to use `cat` for this kind of thing in general, as most programs accept the name of a file in their arguments. If they don't, you can always use `program < filename` rather than `cat filename | program`.
- The use of `ls` is redundant (and possibly prone to bugs caused by files with awkward names). It would be much better to use `for device in *.txt`; do ...`

As a final point, be wary of getting trapped into thinking of one solution to your problem then asking how to implement it. It is much easier for others to come up with the best solution to the more general problem, based on their experience of various tools. In this case, the final answer is very different to the answer to your original question! I've left it below for now.

Let me know if you don't have GNU awk and I'll update my answer.

---

I think that you might be looking for the `paste` command

```
paste file.txt anotherf.txt
```

By default, the two files will be separated by a tab character. To use something else, you can specify the `-d` switch, for example `-d,` would set the separator to a comma instead.

If you want only the first columns from each file, you can use paste with awk:

```
paste -d, <(awk '{print $1}' file.txt) <(awk '{print $1}' anotherf.txt)
```

Assuming that the columns in your two files are separated by a simple delimiter (like a space), `cut` would work too:

```
paste -d, <(cut -f1 -d' ' file.txt) <(cut -f1 -d' ' anotherf.txt)
```

In light of the update to your question, if you already have the content inside two variables, you can use this command instead:

```
paste -d, <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2")
```

Thanks to all who contributed in the comments.

Comment: Probably `paste <(awk '{print $1}' f1) <(awk '{print $1}' f2)`

Comment: or ;) `paste -d, <(cut -f1 -d' ' f1) <(cut -f1 -d' ' f2)`

Comment: As per the new requirement of the OP, `paste <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2")` should make. Btw, I already +1, but get a virtual +1 again for patience on improving the answer!

Comment: thanks! but still got an issue: *Syntax error: "(" unexpected*

Comment: @jayFour Perhaps it would be helpful to show a sample of what the variables contain in the question. Also, try enabling debugging with `set -x`.

Comment: @jayFour In terms of solving the current problem, I'm more interested in the contents of the variable rather than the commands that you're using. Please edit the question to include a few lines from each variable.

Comment: @jayFour The space between `-d,` and `<(` is important :). Also, the command is `paste`, not `parse`. Try this: `paste -d, <(echo "$port") <(echo "$stat") <(echo "$vlan")`. The output isn't exactly what you wanted but is quite similar. What you're trying to do can actually be simplified into one awk statement. I'll take a look at it later on.

Comment: yeah, sorry for typos, they're not in my script :/ fixed now :) but not working...still :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`getline` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) in `awk` to read from a separate file and synchronize the fields:

```
$ awk 'getline line<ARGV[2]{split(line,a)}NR==FNR{print $1,a[1]}' file.txt anotherf.txt
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
```

Comment: Some useful material indeed, thanks.  After reading it, I think my usage of `getline` seems to be appropriate :)